# How to change child process name without excuting exec serie functions?

Tags: c, process

I have a daemon process named `mydaemon`. Now I want to have an other process to send something for me , and when I fork a child process , it has the same name with the parent process. How can I have a different process name without `exec` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under Linux you can use the `prctl()` function to set the process name:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>

prctl(PR_SET_NAME, "foobar");
```