# How to put name of new executable from fork/execlp in /proc exe or cmdline?

Tags: c, linux, process

I've got a small test example that creates a fork(), then has the child launch a new binary through the execlp() function.  It works fine, but when I go to look at things with top/htop, I see the Command field of the new binary is blank.  The /proc/[childpid]/exe entry properly links to the new binary, but how can I get the name of the binary to be visible in top/htop?

Thanks!

Matt

Comment: "*I've got a small test example ...*" daring to show it here? ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change child process name without excuting exec serie functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179356/how-to-change-child-process-name-without-excuting-exec-serie-functions)

Comment: I answered [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38447655/5058676) a couple of days ago. You probably forgot to set the file parameter in your execlp.